# I'm a Python novice trying to use a Free API from Open Weather but I receive {'cod': '404', 'message': 'Internal error'}. How can I fix this?

Tags: api, http-status-code-404, weather, base-url

Type city name : New York

> {'cod': '404', 'message': 'Internal error'}

The City Could Not Be Found?

Process finished with exit code 0

API key is free and activated, maybe I am using the wrong url?

```
import requests    

api_key = 'api_key'

base_url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.0/weather?'  

city_name = input("Type city name : ")  

complete_url = base_url + "appid=" + api_key + "&q=" + city_name  

response = requests.get(complete_url)  

x = response.json()
print(x)

if x["cod"] == "404":  
    print("The City Could Not Be Found?")
else:  
    y = x['main']             

current_temperature = y["temp"]  

current_pressure = y["pressure"]

current_humidity = y["humidity"]

z = x["weather"]  

weather_description = z[0][
    "description"]  

print("Temperature (in kelvin unit) = " + str(current_temperature) +   
      "\n atmospheric pressure (in hPa unit) = " + str(
        current_pressure) + 
      "\n humidity (in percentage) = " + str(current_humidity) +   
      "\n description = " + str(weather_description))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try typing it all in manually to your browser first, to test for the correct layout and parameters e.g.

```
https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=New%20York&appid=your_code_here


{"coord":{"lon":-74.006,"lat":40.7143},"weather":[{"id":804,"main":"Clouds","description":"overcast clouds","icon":"04n"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":287.1,"feels_like":286.93,"temp_min":283.32,"temp_max":290.93,"pressure":1003,"humidity":91},"visibility":10000,"wind":{"speed":8.75,"deg":50,"gust":11.32},"clouds":{"all":90},"dt":1635576402,"sys":{"type":1,"id":4610,"country":"US","sunrise":1635593052,"sunset":1635630898},"timezone":-14400,"id":5128581,"name":"New York","cod":200}
```

See: https://openweathermap.org/current

Comment: wow! thank you, I changed 2.0 to 2.5 and it worked immediately.